# How store column from a .csv file into a list?

Tags: python, csv

I have this code which get me all the data from my `.csv` file with `DictReader`

```
csv_path = "C:/Users/mydata.csv"

csv_database = open(csv_path, delimiters=";")    

dataDict = csv.DictReader(csv_database, delimiter=";")
```

My database is like:

```
"Number0"; "date0"; "id0";...
"Number1"; "date1"; "id1";...
"Number2"; "date2"; "id2";...
...
```

And I want to get all the column in separate lists so they will look like :

```
[Number0, Number1, Number2,...]
[date0, date1, date2,...]
[id0, id1, id2,...]
```

Is there a way to do that, maybe using the headers which I can get with `dataDict.fieldnames`?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I find a solution so here it is :

```
csv_path = "C:/Users/mydata.csv"
csv_database = open(csv_path, delimiters=";")    
data_dict = csv.DictReader(csv_database, delimiter=";")

current_row = 0

number_list = []

for row in data_dict:

    current_row += 1 # Skip heading row

    if current_row == 1:
        continue

    number_list.append(row["Number"]) # Assuming the header of your column is "Number"

# Show results

for number in number_list:
    print number
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.html)
You can do something like this with it:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['hi','hey'],['sfg','asf']])
>>> a.transpose()
array([['hi', 'sfg'],
       ['hey', 'asf']],
      dtype='|S3')
>>> print a.transpose()[1]
['hey' 'asf']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zip(*[line.strip().split(',') for line in open(csv_path).readlines()])
```

Comment: Perhaps if you described why this will work, it will make for a better answer.